# Atomic policy in objc_setAssociatedObject

Tags: objective-c

I can not see any policy(**OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC**) for atomic, when setting object?

```
objc_setAssociatedObject(self, ObjectTagKey, newObjectTag, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

Or is it default and therefore I don't have to care about thread safety?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN` is what you're looking for.

For reference, here are all the possible values (from `objc/runtime.h`):

```
enum {
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN = 0,           
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC = 1, 
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC = 3,   
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN = 01401,       
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY = 01403          
};
```

Comment: I saw this in runtime.h, so I guess that by not using *_NONATOMIC it defaults to ATOMIC? And therefore OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN is ATOMIC b y default? Thanks

Comment: Yes. You can read that in the comments on `objc/runtime.h`.